# Is there any spring cloud part or version where jwt isn't supported?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-data, jwt, spring-cloud

Today I had an interview and during that the interviewer asked me a question that "**now spring cloud doesn't support jwt. So if you want to implement jwt now how can you implement it?**"

I have studied jwt in spring cloud services and it has been absolutely fine. But this question was something completely strange and new for me. **Anybody have ever seen if new spring cloud or spring data doesn't support jwt?** if yes then how can I implement jwt in it? Because I am new in java spring cloud and learning whole spring cloud microservices architecture and jwt with spring security and I am not much aware if the question asked by inteviewer was really right or not. please share your opinion and answer for question if you know it. Thanks

Comment: I don't know why they would say that

Comment: Don't you also need spring-security? Possibly what they were asking